# How can i use suspense with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I haven't found any clear information about that so I decided to ask you. I have app based on redux infrastructure. Is there a way to use `Suspense` in order to wait until the data is fetched by a redux with axios? I'm placing my action call inside `componentDidMount` then of course it goes with a redux flow (with redux thunk and axios) until it will get to the store. Before then however I would like to use Suspense to show a spinner instead of empty fields without data fetched. How could I wait with `Supsense` until data will finally get to the store?

Thank you for any info.

Answer (score 2):

According official React document, [Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#suspense) is used to load component instead of to fetch data :

> If the module containing the OtherComponent is not yet loaded by the time MyComponent renders, we must show some fallback content while we’re waiting for it to load - such as a loading indicator. This is done using the Suspense component.

If you are working with redux, I think you just keep your application simple by handle `loading` state by Redux and showing the indicator within the `render` method like:

```
render(){
  const { isLoading, data } = this.props
  if(isLoading) {
    return <Your indicator component />
  }
  if(isEmpty(data)) {
    return <div>Your data is empty</div>
  }
  return this.renderList(data)
}
```